# ATmega - nested interrupt

Tags: atmega, interrupts

I need to wait on PIN_CHANGE interrupt during pending TIMER interrupt.
Is that right to do it like in code below?
Is the interrupt still enabled during **`do_something_2`**?
What is the right order of **`ENABLE_PCINT`** and **`sei()`**?
How many clock cycles does it take to jump to the `PCINT` routine after `sei()`?

```c
ISR(TIMER1_OVF_vect)        
{
    do_something_1;
    ENABLE_PCINT;
    sei(); 

    char i = 20;
    while(i>0) {
        i--;
    }

    do_something_2;     
}
```

Comment: This sounds like a poor substitute for a timer pin capture function. Have you tried that first? Also, did you mean to leave PCINT enabled forever after?

Comment: @TimWilliams It is for fast reading of AC signal (500kHz). I need to catch rising edge in PCINT. So I poll the pin in Timer until falling edge is found a then quick enable PCINT to be sure the rising edge appears in PCINT. The second part of your Q I mean if interrupt is still enabled in current timer ISR.

Comment: Reading in what respect? You don't need an interrupt at all just to detect that a signal is present. Discriminating signals, is another matter. But I have no idea what you're trying to do here.

Comment: The datasheet explains the sei and interrupt timing. The problem you might face is the time it takes to enter the isr and save the processor state. Maybe you might want to consider the myriad of much faster microcontrollers available today. The AVR was good 20 years ago.

Comment: @Kartman It is ok for me to have a little delayed jump into PCINT ISR because of saving the proc. state. Important for me this delay should be always the same and within some range: 500kHz sine, so half wave is 1us, rising/falling slopes of sine .2us, so I have .6us to get a sample. With 20MHz Xtall clk (0.05us) I have room 12 clock cycles so it should be enough.

Comment: @Kartman I am only interested if PCINT can occur two times in timer ISR since global interrupt has been enabled. Or to get only one PCINT the global interrupt have to be disabled after first PCINT jump?